# Matplotlib date plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using Python and Matplotlib to chart some time-series data. The data series looks like this:

```
2015-08-04 06:00:09,803 INFO 53.0
2015-08-04 06:00:14,802 INFO 51.7
2015-08-04 06:00:19,808 INFO 52.6
2015-08-04 06:00:24,808 INFO 52.5
2015-08-04 06:00:29,806 INFO 51.5
...
```

Conversion of the date portion using `date2num` results in a series of float values which look like this:

```
735814.2501041667
735814.2501620371
735814.2502199074
735814.2502777778
735814.2503356482
...
```

If I then plot these date/time values on the x-axis, I get a series of numbers that don't resemble dates or times. I must be missing something obvious with formatting the dates but can't seem figure out what it is. Ideas?

Comment: Are u ok with a pandas solution?

Comment: Sure, don't know much about Pandas though...

Answer (score 0):

use the `DateFormatter` and related functions to choose how to display your dates.
http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/date_demo.html